# How to merge-left two lists?

Tags: scala

Say that I have two case classes:

```
case class LineItem(name: String, price:Int, discount:Discount)
case class Discount(amount:Int, reason:String)
```

I have list of line items:

L1, L2, L3

and a list of discounts:

D1, D2

How can I merge the discounts into the list of line items?

I initially thought to just zip them and map but that drops L3 from the zipped list.

Comment: `zipAll` with default elements?

Comment: Can you please give an example using code/pseudocode of what you want?

Comment: Considering your `LineItem` class contains a `Discount`, does it make sense to do something akin to a join instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first convert the discounts to a list of `Option[Discount]`, pad the list with `None`s, zip it and map:

```
//items: List[LineItem], discounts: List[Discount]
val discOptions = discounts.map(Some(_)).padTo(items.length, None)

items.zip(discOptions) map {
  case (item, Some(disc)) => item.copy(discount = disc)
  case (item, None) => item
}
```

Comment: This is the most idiomatic approach I've seen to this problem. Good use of types and collection methods. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

`zipLeft` implemented similar to `zipAll`, but ignoring extra elements in right `List`.

```
def zipLeft[A, B](left: List[A], right: List[B], thatElem: B): List[(A, B)] = {
    val b = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[(A, B)]
    val these = left.iterator
    val those = right.iterator
    while (these.hasNext && those.hasNext)
      b += ((these.next(), those.next()))
    while (these.hasNext)
      b += ((these.next(), thatElem))
    b.toList
}
val lst1 = List(1,2,3)
val lst2 = List(4,5)
zipLeft(lst1,lst2,0)//List((1,4),(2,5),(3,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **List.fill(lineItems.size() - discounts.size())(Discount(0,"")** first to fill the discounts with "null" discounts until it matches the line items length, then zip, then map.

Comment: Would Use of Options would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: @SV I like NikolòMartini's answer better than mine, both for the use of **Option** and the use of **padTo** rather than **fill**.  Overall **None** reflects the meaning of no discount better than an explicit zero discount.  I was thinking making **Discount** a case class with **FullPrice** would read more clearly, but types trump names and **Option** is the correct type for this.